# VIM auto braces removement

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I just found out how to make vim automatically create matching braces:

```
inoremap { {}<Esc>ha
inoremap ( ()<Esc>ha
inoremap [ []<Esc>ha
inoremap " ""<Esc>ha
inoremap ' ''<Esc>ha
inoremap ` ``<Esc>ha
```

Now I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically remove a matching brace when removing one of them
It would be easy with an autobrace plugin, but I do not want to install a plugin for bracing
Maybe there is one for auto removing or there is a way to do it without pugins?

Watching forward for your suggestions

Comment: Minor nit: `ha` could be replaced with just `i`.

Comment: Not an answer, as an example, assuming you want to delete the curly brace by pressing `<BS>` while the cursor is inside the empty `{}`, you can add `inoremap <expr> <BS> getline('.') =~ '{\%' . col('.') . 'c}' ? '<BS><Delete>' : '<BS>'`. Therefore, Even if you don't use a plug-in, you may still need to write a simple vim script function according to your actual needs, and then map it, because multiple brackets can add multiple mappings, while `<BS>` mapping can only create one. So for simplicity, you can find a related plug-in, copy its function to vimrc and modify it slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon reading your question, my mind went two ways:

1. use autocommands and all to detect a removal and act accordingly, which sounds awfully complex,
2. or make simple mappings like the ones you already have.

I will go with the second option but we can take this opportunity to simplify your current mappings:

```
inoremap { {}<Esc>ha
```

by removing the unnecessary mode switching:

```
inoremap { {}<Left>
```

There, much cleaner.

Now, the following normal mode mapping should get you close to where you want to be:

```
nnoremap <key> va{o<C-c>m'gvo<C-c>"_x``"_x
```

- visually select pair with `va{`,
- move cursor to other end of selection with `o`,
- leave visual mode with `<C-c>`,
- create context mark with `m'`,
- reselect same visual selection with `gv`,
- move cursor the other end of selection with `o`,
- leave visual mode with `<C-c>`,
- cut closing brace to black hole register with `"_x`,
- jump to previously set context mark with ``` `` ```,
- cut opening brace to black hole register with `"_x`.

See `:help a}`, `:help v_o`, `:help v_ctrl-c`, `:help m'`, `:help gv`, `:help x`, and `:help registers`.

That visual mode dance is not strictly necessary for `[{()}]` because of `:help %`, but it definitely is for `` "'` ``.

There are a few available combos starting with `d`:

```
dc dm dq dr ds du dx dy dz
```

so pick your poison. Assuming you choose the `dx` "leader", you should end up with this:

```
nnoremap dx{ va{o<C-c>m'gvo<C-c>"_x``"_x
" etc.
```

Note that the text object `a{` as a couple of synonyms, `a}` and `aB`, so you might want to cover them, too:

```
nnoremap dx{ va{o<C-c>m'gvo<C-c>"_x``"_x
nmap     dx} dx{
nmap     dxB dx{
" etc.
```

which also holds true for `a(`. Note the *clever* use of non-recursive and recursive mappings.

Since a lot of this is quite repetitive, you might consider creating a "plug" mapping for the repetitive part:

```
xnoremap <Plug>(RemovePair) o<C-c>m'gvo<C-c>"_x``"_x
nnoremap dx{ va{<Plug>(RemovePair)
nmap     dx} dx{
nmap     dxB dx{
nnoremap dx( va(<Plug>(RemovePair)
nmap     dx) dx(
nmap     dxb dx(
nnoremap dx" va"<Plug>(RemovePair)
" etc.
```

See `:help <plug>`.

---

That said, **use Surround**.

Comment: *"Note the clever use of non-recursive and recursive mappings."* - duly noted. I'm impressed. A passing thought: you might even `noremap dx{ va}<Plug>(RemovePair)` as `<Plug>` mappings are always applied.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that `<Plug>` mappings had to be used in recursive mappings. I learned a few things at work and online, today, so this is a good day.